# adding GridView DataKeyNames values gives Resources.ExceptionPolicyNotFound

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm adding a tooltip to a GridView, and am running across an interesting error.  Everything works fine when I have the bound field I'm using to populate my tooltip visible.  When it is hidden, the tooltips are blank (which I expected, since the data doesn't get sent when hidden).  To get around this, I'm using the DataKeyNames attribute to keep the data.  When this is added, it results in the Resources.ExceptionPolicyNotFound exception.

Here is the grid view (with reject reason):

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GrdSearchResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GrdSearchResult_RowDataBound"
        Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GrdSearchResult_PageIndexChanging"
        EmptyDataText="No record found." PageSize="20" CssClass="GridStyle" PagerStyle-CssClass="PagerStyle" EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="EmptyStyle"
        DataKeyNames="RejectReason">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reject Code" DataField="RejectCode"/>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Claim #" DataField="ClaimNbr" />                           
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Member Medicaid #" DataField="MemberMedicaidNbr" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Member Name" DataField="MemberName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Provider Name" DataField="ProviderName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Check(s) Details" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date of Service" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" DataField="ServiceRange" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Claims Link" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RejectReason" DataField="RejectReason" Visible="false" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This is the code that uses the column, but it never gets hit prior to the error.

```
e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = e.Row.Cells[8].Text.ToString();
```

The goal is to set the first column's tooltip to the value of the last (9th) column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what caused the error, but I've decided to handle this in a different way.  Instead of hiding the data field by default, I'm hiding it after I set the tooltip.

```
                    e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = e.Row.Cells[8].Text.ToString();
                    e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
```

The only wrinkle was getting the column header hidden as well, but I managed that with identical code in another section.  The existing code uses

```
                    if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != string.Empty)
```

To look at only data rows and not the header row, so I added.

```
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
            }
```

After the data manipulation was done.